# Splitting file lines and save them in a file

Tags: python, sql

I have 1000 SQL select queries in text file. For example, the bellow query:

```
select first_name, title, salary
from employees, salaries
where
    employees.emp_no = salaries.emp_no
    and first_name = 'attila'
    and last_name = '1UB4pqakE3'
```

I want to save it in another file in this form:

> (first_name,title,salary, employees.emp_no, salaries.emp_no, last_name)

I mean I want to process every line of the original file to keep just the attributes. I wonder how I can do it in Python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should write a MCVE and show some efforts. Could edit your post to produce a reduced sample of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Here a naive solution to your problem using regular expression and set/list comprehension.

First load file into a variable:

```
with open('some_query.sql') as file:
    txt = file.read()
```

Then tokenize the content, remove text values (starting with `'`) and SQL keywords:

```
import re

# Tokenize words
regex = re.compile("([\w._']+)")
tokens = regex.findall(txt)

# Set Comprehension removing text fields:
tokens = { token for token in tokens if not(token.startswith("'")) }

# SQL Keywords:
keywords = {'select', 'from', 'where', 'limit', 'and', 'or', 'not'}

# Identifiers:
identifiers = tokens - keywords
```

For your trial sample it returns:

```
{'employees',
 'employees.emp_no',
 'first_name',
 'last_name',
 'salaries',
 'salaries.emp_no',
 'salary',
 'title'}
```

Which is the sorted list of column identifiers without duplicates.

If order of appearance really matters and duplicates are allowed (like your output suggests), then just change the above code for this one which is a bit less efficient:

```
# Set Comprehension removing text fields:
tokens = [ token for token in tokens if not(token.startswith("'")) ]

# SQL Keywords
keywords = {'select', 'from', 'where', 'limit', 'and', 'or', 'not'}

# Identifiers:
identifiers = tuple([token for token in tokens if not(token in keywords)])
```

This leads to:

```
('first_name',
 'title',
 'salary',
 'employees',
 'salaries',
 'employees.emp_no',
 'salaries.emp_no',
 'first_name',
 'last_name')
```

Finally, write back the `set` into another file:

```
with open('some_query.key', 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(tokens))
```

At this point it is just about encapsulate this code in a function and parameterize the file name in order to apply it to all your files.

Note: This solution also catches table identifiers.

Comment: Thank you dear Jlandercy. I really appreciate it. Could you please adjust the code (the regex part) to skip the tables names from the list.

Comment: I have other queries like (select count(employees.emp_no) from employees,salaries where employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no and deg='6' and title='bio'  ) and (select count(emp_no) from salaries where title='law'). How can I skip parenthesis and just take what inside. Could you please update the regex part to do such cases.

Comment: @user9529190 You have to write a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want other to help you.

Comment: @user9529190 What your asking is not trivial and you seem to have many use cases. When you will have complete your post to meet the MCVE requirements, I could reconsider to refactor my code.

Comment: Dear Jlandercy, It was my second time to ask here. I did not know what you meant by MCVE. I wrote the description and the samples. I want to get help form people who are professional in python. I did not have ideas, so I asked. I am really thankful for your reply, tough it did not work well or as I want . Best...

Comment: @user9529190 No worries, it is why I draw your attention to this specific point. If you do not write a MCVE we will have a lot of comment asking for more stuff and use case you have not stated in your original question.

Comment: @user9529190 If you mind rephrase your question posting a generic file containing all subtleties of your problem and what exactly is the expected output you are likely to get an answer that suits your requirement.